# Deserialize object passed as abstract class by SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, signalr

I have a WebAPI server that has a Hub that replies to Subscribe requests by publishing an `Dictionary<long, List<SpecialParam>>` object.

The list of `SpecialParam` contains items of type `SpecialParamA` & `SpecialParamB` which both inherit `SpecialParam`.

When I try to capture the publish on the client:

```
hubProxy.On<Dictionary<long, List<SpecialParam>>>(hubMethod, res =>
{
    DoStuff();
});
```

The `DoStuff()` method isn't called. If I change the publish return value to `string`, and change the proxy to receive a `string` value, the `DoStuff()` method is called. Therefore, the problem is with the deserialization of the `SpecialParam` Item.

I tried configuring on the server-side:

```
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfig.Resolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

But it didn't help.

I also tried adding to the client:

```
HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnection(hubPath);
hubConnection.JsonSerializer.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto;
hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(hubName);
hubProxy.JsonSerializer.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

And it also didn't help.

In other solutions I found that people defined a new `IParameterResolver`, but it is only called when the server receives the input to the hub method, and not when the output is published from the hub.

Please help!

**UPDATE**

Here is what I caught with fidler:

```
{"$type":"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubResponse, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core","I":"0"}
```

This is what the server replies to the client.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm still trying to figure out how to receive it already deserialized as `Dictionary<long, List<SpecialParam>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by setting in the service:

```
public static void ConfigureApp(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    ...
    var service = (JsonSerializer)GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer));
    service.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
    ...
}
```

and removing the expected type in the client:

```
hubProxy.On(hubMethod, res =>
{
    DoStuff();
});
```

I get the response in json form and I deserialize it with:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
JObject jObject = resp as JObject;
var specialParams = jObject.ToObject<Dictionary<long, List<SpecialParam>>>(serializer);
```

I still don't know how to make my client receive it already deserialized.